# How many cells does brainfuck have?

Tags: brainfuck

Urban Müller's 1993 *Brainfuck* is said to have a tape register of "at least" 30 000 cells. However considering the language deals primarily in base 2, I'd wonder if his "tape" (historically) had `2**15 = 32768` cells instead.

Does it say anywhere the exact number of cells Müller used?

Comment: well, brainfuck is hardly standardized and there isn't a thing called `the brainfuck implementation`. strictly speaking, it should have theoretically infinite number of cells to be Turing complete(I implemented one interpreter in haskell that does infinite cells in both directions).

Comment: According to the source and readme in http://aminet.net/package.php?package=dev/lang/brainfuck-2.lha it was 30000 bytes exactly for the compiler, and looks like only 5000 bytes for the interpreter.

Comment: To quote: "The 30000 array elements and p are being
initialized to zero at the beginning.  Now while this seems to be a pretty
useless language, it can be proven that it can compute every solvable
mathematical problem (if we ignore the array size limit and the executable
size limit)."

Answer (score 1):

The cell amount is *considered* infinite, but you can't really have infinite memory.